# Vado avanti, significato di questa espressione

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, single-words

Ciao,

Volevo sapere se "Vado avanti" si può tradurre come "move on", o se significa semplicemente cercare di farcela con i propri dolori e problemi quotidianamente.

Grazie.

Comment: Dipende dal contesto, se hai la frase completa si può capire il significato.

Comment: Di solito in quell'accezione è “tiro avanti”.

Comment: Dipende molto dal contesto come mostrato a Charo nel commento. Al consolato qui in Germania l´addetto, dopo avere preso i miei dati, disse "Vado avant!" nel senso di "Procedo", oppure se qualcuno mi dice "Vai avanti" per dirmi "Continua" (in quello che faccio o dico), o come anche tra amici quando mi dicono "guarda che la strada é sbagliata" ma testardo come sono dico "vado avanti" nel senso di "Continuo" o "procedo" (lo stesso/ugualmente) (nulla ha che fare con la direzione, potevo anche in retromarcia "andare avanti", lol), e tanti altri casi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dipendendo dal contesto può avere tutti e due i significati che menzioni nella domanda. Alla [voce "avanti" del vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avanti/) si può leggere:

> **a.** Indica la direzione che si ha di fronte, in contrapp. a *dietro*, *indietro*, e si adopera per lo più con verbi di moto: *andare, venire, farsi avanti*; *camminare, andare a. e indietro*, fare su e giù; *un signore che passeggiava nervosamente a. e indietro lungo il vagone, scomparendo a volte per lunghi minuti nella carrozza successiva* (Melania Mazzucco). [...]
>
> **b.** Usi fig.: *andare a., tirare a.*, campare alla meglio, vivere più o meno stentatamente; [...]

Comment: la tua risposta non copre tutte le casistiche in cui puoi usare la frase "Vado avanti!", o meglio non adeguatamente/chiaramente con gli esempi che citi. Ad esempio agli esami universitari piú volte mi é capitato di dire al docente "Vado avanti!" dopo un breve dialogo col quale mi interrompe, in questo caso il moto é figurato anche se il verbo é inteso piú come "procedo"/"continuo". E in merito al "procedo"/"continuo" che piú volte lo si sente in molti uffici durante una pratica, o anche al telefono con l´operatore, altre volte si sente anche "Vado avanti!" (con la pratica/con l´operazione)